# MVC binding to model with list property ignores other properties

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3

I have a basic ViewModel with a property that is a List of complex types. When binding, I seem to be stuck with getting either the list of values, OR the other model properties depending on the posted values (i.e. the view arrangement).

The view model:

```
public class MyViewModel
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Property1 { get; set; }
    public string Property2 { get; set; }

    public List<MyDataItem> Data { get; set; }
}

public class MyDataItem
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public int ParentId { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string Value { get; set; }
}
```

The controller actions:

```
    public ActionResult MyForm()
    {
        MyViewModel model = new MyViewModel();

        model.Id = 1;
        model.Data = new List<MyDataItem>() 
        { 
            new MyDataItem{ Id = 1, ParentId = 1, Name = "MyListItem1", Value = "SomeValue"}
        }; 

        return View(model);
    }

    [HttpPost]
    public ActionResult MyForm(MyViewModel model)
    {
        //...

        return View(model);
    }
```

Here is the basic view (without the list mark-up)

```
@using (Html.BeginForm()) {
    @Html.ValidationSummary(true)
    <fieldset>
        <legend>My View Model</legend>

        @Html.HiddenFor(model => model.Id)

        <div class="editor-label">
            @Html.LabelFor(model => model.Property1)
        </div>
        <div class="editor-field">
            @Html.EditorFor(model => model.Property1)
            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Property1)
        </div>

        <div class="editor-label">
            @Html.LabelFor(model => model.Property2)
        </div>
        <div class="editor-field">
            @Html.EditorFor(model => model.Property2)
            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Property2)
        </div>

        <p>
            <input type="submit" value="Save" />
        </p>
    </fieldset>
}
```

When posted back to the controller, I get the 2 property values and a null value for the 'Data' property as expected.

[image: Without List Mark-up]

If I add the mark-up for the List as follows (based on the information in this [Scott Hanselman post](http://www.hanselman.com/blog/ASPNETWireFormatForModelBindingToArraysListsCollectionsDictionaries.aspx) and [Phil Haack's post](http://haacked.com/archive/2008/10/23/model-binding-to-a-list.aspx)):

```
<div class="editor-field">
@for (int i = 0; i < Model.Data.Count(); i++)
{
    MyDataItem data = Model.Data[i];
    @Html.Hidden("model.Data[" + i + "].Id", data.Id)
    @Html.Hidden("model.Data[" + i + "].ParentId", data.ParentId)
    @Html.Hidden("model.Data[" + i + "].Name", data.Name)
    @Html.TextBox("model.Data[" + i + "].Value", data.Value)
}
</div>
```

The 'Data' property of the model is successfully bound but the other properties are null.

[image: With List Mark-up]

The form values posted are as follows:

```
Id=1&Property1=test1&Property2=test2&model.Data%5B0%5D.Id=1&model.Data%5B0%5D.ParentId=1&model.Data%5B0%5D.Name=MyListItem1&model.Data%5B0%5D.Value=SomeValue
```

Is there a way to get both sets of properties populated or am I just missing something obvious?

**EDIT:**

For those of you who are curious. Based on the answer from [MartinHN](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2972/martinhn), the original generated mark-up was:

```
<div class="editor-field">
    <input id="model_Data_0__Id" name="model.Data[0].Id" type="hidden" value="1" />
    <input id="model_Data_0__ParentId" name="model.Data[0].ParentId" type="hidden" value="1" />
    <input id="model_Data_0__Name" name="model.Data[0].Name" type="hidden" value="MyListItem1" />
    <input id="model_Data_0__Value" name="model.Data[0].Value" type="text" value="SomeValue" />        
</div>
```

The new generated mark-up is:

```
<div class="editor-field">
    <input id="Data_0__Id" data-val="true" name="Data[0].Id" type="hidden" value="1" data-val-number="The field Id must be a number." data-val-required="The Id field is required." />
    <input id="Data_0__ParentId" name="Data[0].ParentId" type="hidden" value="1"  data-val="true" data-val-number="The field ParentId must be a number." data-val-required="The ParentId field is required." />
    <input id="Data_0__Name" name="Data[0].Name" type="hidden" value="MyListItem1" />
    <input id="Data_0__Value" name="Data[0].Value" type="text" value="SomeValue" />        
</div>
```

Which results in the following posted values:

```
Id=1&Property1=test1&Property2=test2&Data%5B0%5D.Id=1&Data%5B0%5D.ParentId=1&Data%5B0%5D.Name=MyListItem1&Data%5B0%5D.Value=SomeValue
```

Notice there's no 'model.' in the name and posted values...

Comment: Not to high-jack the tread or anything.. But how would one make an update to the existing public List<MyDataItem> Data { get; set; } - add an item, subtract, etc then update the parent model on the client without refreshing the screen? How about if Data is null, and can only be known at run time based on user's selection of Parent models' other properties? Well, I guess it is a bit of a high-jack hopefully we are going in the same direction : )

Answer (score 36, accepted):

Try to change the code for the Data collection to this, and let MVC take care of the naming:

```
<div class="editor-field">
@for (int i = 0; i < Model.Data.Count(); i++)
{
    @Html.HiddenFor(m => m.Data[i].Id)
    @Html.HiddenFor(m => m.Data[i].ParentId)
    @Html.HiddenFor(m => m.Data[i].Name)
    @Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.Data[i].Value)
}
</div>
```

Comment: I honestly cannot believe I missed that. Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 12):

Alternatively you could have created an `EditorTemplate` for your nested ViewModel as follows.

```
@model MyDataItem
@Html.HiddenFor(model => model.Id)
@Html.HiddenFor(model => model.ParentId)
@Html.HiddenFor(model => model.Name)
@Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.Value)
```

Create a folder named 'EditorTemplates' in your 'Shared' folder and save the above as 'MyDataItem.cshtml'.

Then in your View, just call the following instead of the `foreach` loop:

```
@Html.EditorFor(model => model.Data)
```

Feels a bit less hackier IMO :)

Answer (score 6):

Just my 2 cents but something worth noting with this issue - the data member in the View Model must be defined as a public property for the postback model binding to work. 
I had a very similar problem to the above but used a public data member in my View Model. The same HTML is generated as shown above and all looks well but the model binder threw back an empty collection. Worth watching for...