# Bindind all elements of a window to an object

Tags: c#, windows, windows-store-apps, winrt-xaml

Have a novice question.  I have an app I created as an experiment, (C#, XAML).  In my main windows, I have 2 textboxes. The first textbox is a value that user types in that a column in a GridView will be multiplied by to populate the GridView.  The second column is a value that the user types in depicting how many rows will be created in the gridview.  Obviously, I have a gridview on this same page that has 2 columns.

What I am trying to do is when the user types a value in either of the textboxes the GridView will automatically populate the columns and rows.  How can I do that?

My Class:

public class myClass : INotifyPropertyChanged
        {
            int valueA = 0;
            int myRows = 0;
            private ObservableCollection myCollection = new ObservableCollection();

```
        public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

        private void NotifyPropertyChanged(String propertyName = "")
        {
            if (PropertyChanged != null)
            {
                PropertyChanged(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
            }
        }

        public int ValueA
        {
            get { return valueA; }
            set
            {
                valueA = value;

                NotifyPropertyChanged();
            }

        }

        public int MyRows
        {
            get { return myRows; }
            set
            {
                myRows = value;
                NotifyPropertyChanged();
            }
        }

        private myGridValues PopulateGridValues()
        {
            myCollection.Clear();
            double tempColumn2Value = 0;
            for (int i = 0; i <= myRows - 1; i++)
            {
                myGridValues tempGridValueClass = new myGridValues(i + 1, tempColumn2Value);
                tempColumn2Value = tempColumn2Value * valueA;
                myCollection.Add(tempGridValueClass);
            }
            NotifyPropertyChanged();
            return myCollection;
        }

        public ObservableCollection<myGridValues> MyCollection
        {
            get { return myCollection; }
        }

        class myGridValues
        {
            int column1Value = 0;
            double column2Value = 0;

            public myGridValues(int a, double b)
            {
                column1Value = a;
                column2Value = b;
            }
        }
    }My XAML for GridView<GridView x:Name="MyGridView" ItemsSource="{Binding Path=MyCollection}">
                <GridView.ItemTemplate>
                    <DataTemplate>
                        <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
                            <TextBlock  Text="{Binding Column1Value}" Foreground="White" Margin="0,0,25,0"/>
                            <TextBlock Text="{Binding Column2Value}"  Foreground="White" Margin="0,0,25,0"/>
                         </StackPanel>
                    </DataTemplate>
                </GridView.ItemTemplate> 
            </GridView>
```

Pardon my not understanding.  I do get the gridview to populate with rows.  (I can tell that they are there because if you hover the mouse over the gridview they are there, but the values in each rows textboxes are blank)  What am I doing wrong?

Lets say we have an app and on the main page there are 3 controls.  2 textboxes and 1 gridview.  Lets that in the constructor of the page I have this.

public myClass mc= new myClass();

```
    public MainWindow()
    {
        this.InitializeComponent();
        this.DataContext = mc;     MyGridView.ItemSource = mc.MyCollection
        ...The two text boxes are just numerical values.  The first textbox is how the values will be populated, and the second textbox tellsthe grid how many rows to make.So lets say that in the first textbox the user types in "2"And the second they type in 5.  Meaning, "Do this 5 times"The grid has two columns, the first column is just the counter and the second column is the value.  Therefore the grid would be populated as such1 22  43  84  165 32The text of both textboxes is bound to the class, "mc", properties
```

So as you can see, if the user enters a value in either textbox, because they are bound to the class, the GridView automaticallygets updated.The problem I was having is that, I got the rows to populate the GridView, but the values in the columns are not there.  But yet, indebug mode, I can see that the ObservableCollection property of class mc, is indeed populated with the desired values.  Am I not binding the textboxes in the GridView correctly?

Answer (score 0):

since this an experiment I think you will find good direction [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6585585/mvc-binding-to-model-with-list-property-ignores-other-properties).  they ae using a list instead of a collection but it should not matter, the mvc and built in functionality is what you are seeking and this a pretty good example.

Comment: I appreciate it, but I am using XAML and C#.  I would prefer to use the observable collection.

Answer (score 0):

Implement INotifyPropertyChanged in the myGridValues class/properties.

Why do you call NotifyPropertyChanged in the PopulateGridValues method? The ObservableCollection already handles this for you (for it's items).

I suggest you take at a look at the samples (C#/XAML) and how the basics work.
http://code.msdn.microsoft.com/windowsapps/site/search?f%5B0%5D.Type=ProgrammingLanguage&f%5B0%5D.Value=C%23&f%5B0%5D.Text=C%23

Comment: Sorry that was a typo.  The rows are populating the gridview, but the values are not showing up in the textboxes on the individual rows.  What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Yeah, the grid rows are populated, but the cell-binding won't work if you don't provider a class that implements INotifyPropertyChanged.